# PHP GD Library making a collage issues

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to create a collage of images using the GD library however all I ever get displayed on my screen is a broken image link.

The im source files are gotten from a facebook URL - I checked the links to the images and all are valid.

My loop code is below

```
$pos_counter=0;
        $new_collage = imagecreatetruecolor(851,315); // Create our canvas
        $pos = array(array(0,0), array(206,0), array(412,0), array(618,0));
        $width = 206;
        foreach($collage_images as $image)
        {
            $current_image =     imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
            imagecopymerge($new_collage, $current_image,      $pos[$pos_counter][0], $pos[$pos_counter][1],0,0,206,206);
            imagedestroy($current_image);
            $pos_counter++;
        }
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($new_collage);
```

This simply returns a broken image link.

I started debugging my code:

for example looping through just trying to output each image individually also returns a broken image link:

```
foreach($collage_images as $image)
        {
            $current_image =imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
            header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            imagejpeg($current_image);

        }
```

I also tried echoing $current_image however I was only returned with resource ID's which shows to me the imagecreatefromstring is working as it is not returning false?

Comment: *"all I ever get displayed on my screen is a broken image link"* - jup, something went wrong. What about first finding out what went wrong? I mean this can mean a lot including that the network isn't working right any longer or the browser is not able to display such image format. So please drill this down a bit. You will profit from doing so more than getting answers btw.

Comment: @hakre Thats what I have been trying to do - the images from the facebook api are all in jepg format which is what I create. The images I get for the collage are all valid URL's I'm happy to post anything here that could help people help me. I really dont know where else to turn unfortunately. sorry and thanks

Comment: Do you do error logging? For development, enable the highest possible value (log everything, incl. STRICT NOTICES and WARNINGS), also you need to do your own error checkings. Was the image created from string properly? Check the return value! Report these kind of errors your own as well, make your program deal with such cases of error.

Comment: Hi - looks like I've figured it - turning on error reporting helped me get there! thank you SO much :) sorry for the trouble - if you add an answer I'll happily accept it for you right away so you get the cred!

Comment: I fear that is not worth an answer. I'm happy if you learned a lesson for live ;) Next time you see somebody else here with similar trouble, help them. That's better than giving me some points of which I think I have enough ;)

Comment: well thank you loads! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hakre advised to turn on error reporting. did so and found that I wasn't passing in image opacity.

imagecopymerge should have been

```
imagecopymerge($new_collage, $current_image, $pos[$pos_counter][0], $pos[$pos_counter][1],0,0,206,206,100);
```